# Unique ID for WordPress shortcodes when used more than once on a page?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, shortcode

I’m currently coding a WordPress shortcode and it has some jquery involved. For jquery to work properly I need to use a div with a unique #ID. If the shortcode is used once, it works fine, but if they were to use the shortcode more than once on a page, it would break the javascript.

So, I’m wondering if there is some way to use a unique ID every time the shortcode is called? Or some way to have a different ID if the shortcode is used more than once on a page?

Suppose i have the shortcode function

```
function my_shortcode() { 
 $my_shortcode='<div id="demo">My content</div>'; 
 return $my_shortcode;
} //end function
```

and jquery

```
 $("#demo").click(function{

    autoplay: true,
});
```

Comment: Is an ID necessary? You could use a class `.demo` instead

Comment: Yes you solution will work. But `autoplay` can be `false` for other ID. @diggy

Answer (score 8):

You can use a static variable

```
static $i = 1;
$i++;
```

and use it as part of the ID

```
return "<div id='shortcode-div-{$i}'></div>";
```

Answer (score 1):

You are [free to set](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API) the shortcode’s id among with other parameters:

```
[gallery id="123" size="medium"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using an UUID.

In my projects I generate it and attach it the the `$atts` element.

```
add_shortcode('some_shortcode', function ($atts, $content = null) {
  ...

  $atts['uuid'] = uniqid();
  ...

  return 'I have a unique ID: ' . $atts['uuid'];
}
```

This can be easily attached to a data attribute, e.g.

```
return echo '
  <div data-group-uuid="' . $atts['uuid'] . '">
    I'm a container with a unique ID
  </div>
';
```